# Why can't I select a single element in LINQ-To-XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm having a  devil of a time selecting the value of a single element in my XML document

My document looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MySettings>
  <AttachmentsPath>Test</AttachmentsPath>
  <PendingAttachmentsPath>Test2</PendingAttachmentsPath>
</MySettings>
```

I've tried to do the following:

```
 XElement mySettings = XElement.Load("MySettings.xml");

 string AttachmentsPath = (from e in mySettings.Descendants("MySettings")
                              select e.Element("AttachmentsPath")).SingleOrDefault().Value;
```

or

```
 XElement mySettings = XElement.Load("MySettings.xml");

     string AttachmentsPath = mySettings.Element("AttachmentsPath").Value;
```

And none of these work.  I keep getting a:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 33:
>   x => x.Type); Line 34:  Line 35:
>   AttachmentsPath = (from e in
>   mySettings.Descendants("Settings")
>   Line 36:
>   select
>   e.Element("AttachmentsPath")).SingleOrDefault().Value;
>   Line 37:

I can see that it loaded in the XML document correctly.

What am I doing wrong in trying to access this single settings value in my xml document?  Which way is the proper way?

Answer (score 3):

As "MySettings" is the root node it does not have a descendant called "MySettings"

try

```
 var AttachmentsPath = (from e in mySettings.Descendants("AttachmentsPath")
                               select e).SingleOrDefault().Value;
```

however as SingleOrDefault returns null if there is no node maybe you could try this as safer

```
var AttachmentsPathElement = (from e in mySettings.Descendants("AttachmentsPath")
                               select e).SingleOrDefault();

            if(AttachmentsPathElement != null)
            {
                AttachmentsPath = AttachmentsPathElement.Value;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
string path = mySettings.Element("AttachmentsPath").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect code, default of a class is `null` , if default is returned you will get a null reference exception.

```
SingleOrDefault().Value
```

Second of all, if your 2nd approach doesn't work that most likely means you cannot load the XML file correctly, or it cannot find the Element "AttachmentsPath" in the XML.

```
 XElement mySettings = XElement.Load("MySettings.xml");
 string AttachmentsPath = mySettings.Element("AttachmentsPath").Value;
```

Comment: it shouldn't be returning null.  Given the XML I just gave you above.

Comment: @Godel, thats not the point. You shouldn't try to access any properties or methods after calling *SingleOrDefault()* without first checking if its null. In any code that is bad practice.

Comment: If it should always return something (never null), it's better to use Single()

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, all you have to do is specify the root element where the AttachmentPath resides.

That's it...

```
string attachmentsPath= mySettings.Root.Element("MySettings")
                .Elements("AttachmentsPath").SingleOrDefault().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just dealing with something like this a couple hours ago. It turned out that the element I was searching for didn't exist. Is it possible you don't have an element named "Settings" in your document?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading a document in XElement? Why not XDocument?

You could try this:

```
XDocument mySettings = XDocument.Load("MySettings.xml");

string AttachmentsPath = mySettings.Root.Element("AttachmentsPath").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try on this way.I tested this code its working fine

```
  XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

    XElement page = xmlDoc.Descendants("MySettings").FirstOrDefault();

   string AttachmentsPath  =  page.Descendants("AttachmentsPath").First().Value;

   string PendingAttachmentsPath=  page.Descendants("PendingAttachmentsPath").First().Value;
```